# ISBN converter working but trouble with input to output

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

After looking at all the suggested threads, which didn't help, so I'm post ing this. I'm new to javascript and I've coded this algo to take a user input that is a string of 10 digits, convert it to an array and then perform a calculation to get a 13 digit ISBN number (I'm a library information technology student)

When I copy and past my code, not all of it shows up and it says I have code that's not formatted as code. This isn't for my homework, I'm going beyond the requirements by trying to do javascript so there's nothing unethical about asking for help I don't think.

I tried posting my code but it says it's not code so if you follow this link you can see a picture of my code.

Thanks for any insight, input comments or demands for clarification or anything.

https://i.postimg.cc/vmx7hB7Q/code.png

Comment: What says it's not formatted as code?

Comment: Just paste the code, highlight all of it and Ctrl/Cmd + K (indent all of it by 4 spaces). That should be enough to format it in markdown. If it's too long, just add the relevant snippet.

Comment: Copy the critical part of the code and click the {} button. Try again please

Comment: Going through the picture!

Comment: I can't see element with id v, your event listener points to undefined function myfunction. So many errors! Try pasting again, I am here to help.

Comment: ok thank you!! here you go, Edwin and Joseph.

it's too long to paste in a reply, sorry for being so awkward here. I'll show a better picture: 

https://postimg.cc/CZWgZv55

Comment: @KenRichard Copy and paste your code in the question instead of images as links, links may and will expire

Comment: @YashKaranke Thank you, Yash I have posted it in an answer because it did not seem to fit in the comment field. There may be too many errors to help with, I'm going through the other comments but I don't understand them well because I am new to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="input" maxlength="10" size="7">  
            <button id="input" onclick="myfunction();">Click me</button>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js">
                var input = "input";
                document.getElementById("input").value = input; 


                function assign(arr, vars) {
                var x = {};
                var num = math.min(arr.length, vars.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
                    x[vars[i]] = arr[i];
                    }
                    return x;
                    }
                    var arr =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
                    var x = assign(arr, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',]);
                    var z = (9 + 21 + 8 + (var a*3) + var b + (var c*3) + var d + (var e*3) + var f + (var g*3) + var h + (var i*3) + var j);
                    var w = (var z % 10);
                    var v = ("978" + var a, var b, var c, var d, var e, var f, var g, var h, var i, var w);
                    document.getElementById('v').innerHTML = var v;

            </script>

            <div id="output"> </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Honestly, there are so many things wrong here that I'm not sure anyone can help you. Delete this question and post another one where you actually put the code in the question, and explain more carefully and succinctly what you need your algorithm to do (e.g. a sample input and output).

Comment: Thank you, ecg8, will do after class.